# Store data in database after run composer install command in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, composer-php

I'm working on Laravel 10 project and I want to add some data to database when I run the composer install <package_name>. To do that, I have created a custom PHP file and call that postPackageInstall function in composer.json file.

Here how I add that to my composer.json file

```
    {
    
    <-- OTHER COMPOSER JSON DATA -->

    "scripts": {
        "post-package-install": [
            "Widgets\\PackageInstaller::postPackageInstall"
        ]
      },
    <-- OTHER COMPOSER JSON DATA -->
    }
```

And here is my custom PHP file look like.

```
<?php

namespace Widgets;

use Composer\Installer\PackageEvent;
use Composer\Script\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PackageInstaller
{
    protected static $packageName = "";

    public static function postPackageInstall(PackageEvent $event)
    {
        // Get installing package
        $operation = $event->getOperation();

        $package = method_exists($operation, 'getPackage')
            ? $operation->getPackage()
            : $operation->getInitialPackage();

        DB::table('widgets')->insert(['name' => $package->getName()]);
    }
}
```

In here my idea is getting package name and store that name in database after I run composer install command. But the issue is, it throws an error

```
In Facade.php line 350:           
  A facade root has not been set.
```

I assumed that because Laravel is not fully loaded when it comes to this stage. Also, I have tried to run an Artisan command in the post-package-install script. DB queries are working in the command, but I was unable to get the package name inside the command like script.

Is there any other way to achieve this or fix these issues?

Comment: did you try it by using and creating this kind of structure by `make:command` and then adding artisan run command under scripts in composer.json?

Comment: I tried the making command, and I was able to add data to the database. But I couldn't get the package name inside the command handler function. PackageEvent not worked inside the command file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (Using Laravel `DB` facade):

```
namespace Widgets;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Composer\Installer\PackageEvent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PackageInstaller
{
    protected static $packageName = "";

    public static function postPackageInstall(PackageEvent $event)
    {
        $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
    
        $operation = $event->getOperation();

        $package = method_exists($operation, 'getPackage')
            ? $operation->getPackage()
            : $operation->getInitialPackage();

        DB::table('widgets')->insert(
            ['name' => $package->getName()]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom artisan command with the DB logic.
2. Allow passing data to it via CLI arguments.
3. Update `postPackageInstall()` to run the command via [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: I tried this method and exec() not worked

Comment: @VirajMadhushan what was the error?

Comment: There isn't any error returned. Seems like exec() is not working, or code not reaching to that point. Not sure about the reason exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it like this. Since Laravel isn't fully loaded in that post-package-uninstall stage, I used row PHP database queries to store data.

```
public static function postPackageInstall(PackageEvent $event)
    {
        // Get installing package
        $operation = $event->getOperation();
        $package = method_exists($operation, 'getPackage')
            ? $operation->getPackage()
            : $operation->getInitialPackage();

        // Extract package name
        $packageName = $package->getName();

        // Perform database operation
        $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_database', 'username', 'password');
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO widgets (name) VALUES (:name)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $packageName);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

This method is not clean. But it does work in "post-package-uninstall" scripts in Laravel.

Comment: You can use Laravel's `DB` facade after bootstrapping the application. Have a look at my answer.